# Writing to mysql using php and prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql

I have the below code in "profile_server.php" but nothing is being written to the database and I cant figure out why. I appreciate your help :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $id = $_SESSION['id']; // Retrieved from previous session
    //Declaring variables
    $country = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['country']);
    $province = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['province']);
    $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['city']);

    $sql_u_details = $db->prepare ("UPDATE user_details 
                                    SET (country, province, city) 
                                    VALUES (?, ?, ?) 
                                    WHERE id = ? ");

    $sql_u_details->bind_param("ssss", $country, $province, $city, $id);
    $sql_u_details->execute();
    mysqli_query($db, $sql_u_details);

}
```

Comment: Because your `update` syntax is incorrect?

Comment: One of the joys of prepared statements is that it dispenses with the need for all that real_escape stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your sql statement to the following:

```
$sql_u_details = $db->prepare ("UPDATE user_details 
                                SET country = ?, province = ?, city = ? 
                                WHERE id = ?");
```

Comment: I did but nothing changed. Also I notice that the page proceeds to a blank page but not as instructed by the header I have: "header('location: ../index.php');"

Comment: Can you check that the $_POST['submit'] variable is true. Add echo "form working"; exit(); after the if statement

Comment: Thanks fraggley, it was indeed $_POST['submit'] variable is true.

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks again :)